# Bootstrap tooltip change class and over ride styling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I have an action that checks if a field is blank or not and then triggers a tooltip to be shown if it is blank.  The tooltip is not shown unless the field is blank.  When the action is executed the tooltip is showing but it is showing at the top of the parent div and then moves to the bottom when the field is hovered over.  I would like the tooltip to show on the bottom upon the action and hover.

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-5" >
  <%= label_tag :first_name, "First Name", class: "large-white-font" %>
  <%= ff.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name', style: "padding-left: 5%", "data-toggle"=>"tooltip", "data-placement"=>"bottom", "title"=>"Oops, please enter"%>
</div>
```

JS

```
if ($(element).val() === ""){
    $(element).tooltip("show");
} else{
    $(element).tooltip("destroy");      
};
```

CSS when at incorrectly at the top after action

```
element.style {
top: 3px;
left: 0px;
display: block;
}

newmedia="all"
.tooltip.bottom {
margin-top: 3px;
padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Any eyes see what I can't?

Comment: Any chance you could share an example? Have you tried inspecting it with dev tools? Can you check what is happening to the css on the tooltip before and after the input hover states?

Comment: I added the CSS to the question.  It is the style top: 3px that is messing things up.  I'm not sure where it's coming from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ovveride the unwanted styling I added a class to the tooltip

JS

```
$(element).tooltip({
  template: '<div class="tooltip tooltip-adjust-bottom">
  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">
  </div></div>'
}).tooltip("show");
```

CSS

```
.tooltip-adjust-bottom{
  top: auto !important;
  left: 35px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try removing data-toggle and data-placement from the input field and instead add:</strike>

```
$(element).tooltip({
    placement : 'bottom'
});
```

to your javascript. I think the issue is that you are showing it with javascript but its not taking into account the `"data-placement"=>"bottom"` attribute until you have hovered over it.

**Update**
I take it back, something else must be happening. It seems to be working fine [here](http://www.bootply.com/zpkQDyj0nH), I think there most be something else in your javascript that is adding the other css.

Comment: How should I pass that through with this type of call? 
$(e12).prev().find("input:first").tooltip("show");
is it?
$(e12).prev().find("input:first").tooltip("show", {placement: "bottom"});

Comment: Not sure sorry, I was wondering the same thing when I was typing my answer and was just hoping that you would know how to combine them :). Though what you have got does look right, try it and see if it works? I think $(e12).prev().find("input:first").tooltip({placement: "bottom"}).tooltip("show"); should also work but it's not as concise.

Comment: hmm still stumped. Neither worked. Tanks for your help so far...trying to add a class that overrides the unwanted styling.